# Is there a function in Python to multiple a number by another X times and produce the sum? See description

Tags: python

Essentially I have a list of numbers `[5,2,4]` that I want to multiply by 0.5 x number of times and get the sum of, where the number of times is also given in a list `[3,5,7]`.

Taking 5 and 3 of the first element of both lists it would be `(5*0.5) + (2.5*0.5) + (1.25 *0.5)`

Could anyone help with how to write this, assume there's some sort of loop and range function which would apply here?

Comment: `numpy` can already do this with its arrays, have you tried that library? Or do you need to write this from scratch for some reason?

Comment: no can do it in numpy too, just need some direction on the function name perhaps? I'm pretty new to python so please bare with me

Comment: You can just straight-up multiply a numpy array by a number; it's not a particular function. I'd recommend finding some tutorials and other info on it since it's such a powerful library.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do, an what you are struggling with? What exactly do you mean by "multiply by 0.5 x number of times and get the sum of"? How does "5 and 3" translate to ``(5*0.5) + (2.5*0.5) + (1.25 *0.5)`` – where do the ``2.5`` and ``1.25`` come from? Do you mean something akin to Σ_{k=1}^{3} 5 x 0.5^k?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yep im struggling writing code, or function which does the following. I want to do (5*0.5) + (2.5*0.5) + (1.25 *0.5). The 5 translates to the first number which will be mutiplied by 0.5. Every result thereafter (i.e 5 * 0.5 = 2.5) (2.5) will need to also be divided by 0.5. The 3 comes from the number of times I need to multiply each result by if that makes sense? I then need to sum all of those values 2.5 + 1.25 + 0.75 as a final output

Answer (score 0):

The formulation to your question is very unclear for something that looks so much like homework.

I think you are trying to ask this:

> Given two arrays `X` and `N`, I need to compute a third array `Y` so that `Y = V(X, N)`.
>
> V is defined as the sum of "n" terms of the suite U defined by:
>
> - U(0) = 0.5 * x
> - U(n + 1) = 0.5 * U(n)
>
> For instance, for x=5 and n=3, I need to find:
>
> `(5 * 0.5) + (5 * 0.5 * 0.5) + (5 * 0.5 * 0.5 *0.5) = 4.375`

```
def V(x, n):
    acc = 0
    for i in range(n):
       x *= 0.5
       acc += x
    return acc

X = [5, 2, 4]
N = [3, 5, 7]
Y = [V(X[i], N[i]) for i in range(3)]

print(Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's definitely not the best way of doing it but it should do the job:

```
list1 = [5, 2, 4]
list2 = [3, 5, 7]
def get_result(list1, list2):
   
    list3 = [] // Result list
    for i in range(list1):
        result = i
        for j in range(list2[i]):
            result*=0.5
            list3.append(result)

    return list3
```

I haven't tested this, so it may not work.
As someone commented, this is far better done in numpy. You wanted a function so here you go.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is multiplying the values in your numbers list by the sum of powers of the base (0.5) from 1 up to the power specified in your other list.

You can convert each of the power levels to a multiplier value using a mathematical formula and apply that multiplier to the numbers list

```
numbers = [5,2,4]
powers  = [3,5,7]
base    = 0.5

result = [ n * base * (base**p-1)/(base-1) for n,p in zip(numbers,powers) ]

print(result) # [4.375, 1.9375, 3.96875]
```

The formula for the sum of powers is derived from the same principle as the one we use to express a number in any base.

This implies that the sum of the first **p** powers of the base (from zero) will be :

`(base**p-1)/(base-1)`

For example, the sum of the first 5 powers of 10 would be given by:

`(10**5-1)/9` = 11111

which is equivalent to `10**0 + 10**1 + 10**2 + 10**3 + 10**4`

Since this formula is zero-based and thus includes the base raised to the zeroth power, we can multiply it by the base to obtain the desired result:

`base*(base**p-1)/(base-1)`

Which, in the above example would be equivalent to:

`10**1 + 10**2 + 10**3 + 10**4 + 10**5` = 111110

*Note that, if you don't want to use math reasoning, you can obtain the powers using a list comprehension and use sum on that list.  This will be less efficient but can also be expressed in a single line:*

```
[ sum(n*base**i for i in range(1,p+1)) for n,p in zip(numbers,powers) ]
```